# Is there way to deploy control center on remote machine?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am trying to deploy control center as a Docker container.

reference : https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/installation/docker

Above configuration works if docker and GridGain are running on the same host.

I am trying to deploy docker on a different host other than the GridGain nodes.
Which parameter needs to be updated/changed in order to connect control center to the GridGain server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the other way around: the cluster connects to Control Center.

In your cluster you need to tell is where it can find the Control Center front end:

```
{GRIDGAIN_HOME}/bin/management.sh --uri https://control_center_uri:8008
```

It's in the [documentation here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/getting-started/connect/connect-gridgain-cluster#control-center-uri).